# Add global gradle.properties to Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, environment

I'm having difficulty getting the upload task for our projects to work with the bmuschko/gradle-nexus-plugin.

On my dev. machine it works fine, I have a global ~/.gradle/gradle.properties where I supplied my nexusUsername/pass variables.

How can I add the same configuration to our CI server? I have the dreaded 401 unauthorized. I didn't see any options in "Global Tool Configuration" for a global Gradle configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my issue, my nologon jenkins user had created a home directory and gradle installations for my versions. I created the same file in ~/.gradle/ for the jenkins user.